# Laravel move uploaded file manually

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using sub domain to handle my images, and other stuffs.

is it safe every time user upload a image and at my backend i always move it manually?

```
   file = $request->file;
   $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
   $file->move('/home/subdomain/public/tmp/', $filename);
```

Will it be a problem in the future if there is a lot of request?

Thanks

Comment: why are you calling it manual man...its automatic i see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe moving images in this way.

You can use following code to give every image a unique name before moving it.

```
$filename = time().rand(0,9999);
```

Now every image will have it's unique name in your directory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You can also concatenate original name with this hash if you want. :)

Comment: yep. i use md5 the name and time together

Comment: Yes, now it should be handled properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to do that but there isn't any guarantee that the filename will be unique.  I could upload a file called myfile.jpg and you could upload a different file also called myfile.jpg and they would over-write each other.

Better to create some kind of hash or unique ID for each filename and store the file there.  You can also make a directory with a hash name and store the file inside that directory.

Other than that your function is safe.

Comment: yep. i will make it hash. i just want to know is it safer or not. because i've tried using filesystem but it keep failing. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the file name is unique append the current time stamp to the file name

```
$file = 'myImage.jpg';
$filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME); 
$extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$uniqueName = $filename.'_'.Carbon::now().extension;
```

Note: Include the Carbon\Carbon namespace if necessary.

Hope this is helpful.